# View MXF in Xcode project for Video Organizer app

Tags: xcode, video, avfoundation

I'm attempting to build a simple Xcode Mac app for organizing video clips. I use MXF video footage a lot. I can't find a way to make those clips play inside of AVFoundation in Xcode.

I imagine FFMPEG could make this possible somehow. But if I went to sell this at any point, I might have to remove FFMPEG completely. I don't know. Just thinking out loud.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this library at my workplace, it's a post facility and we deal with MXFs all the time.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/bmxlib/

Specifically I use the mxf2raw tool that comes bundled with it. 
It gives raw audio and video streams as the output. I deal mostly with audio but you could probably take the raw video file and read it frame by frame using AVFoundation.